# Android - How do I make two Views receive AND EXECUTE the same touch event?

Tags: android, events, view, touch, touch-event

I have a RelativeLayout that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#65ffffff" >

<com.sonyericsson.zoom.ImageZoomView
    android:id="@+id/zoomview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a bunch of touch events set for that RelativeLayout. However, the com.sonyericsson.zoom.ImageZoomView also have its own logic to handle touch events.

When I perform any touch event in the screen, the touch listeners of the com.sonyericsson.zoom.ImageZoomView class is called first (which is what I expect). The problem is that, if I return "true" in that touch event, the touch listeners of the RelativeLayout **ARE NOT CALLED**. Whereas if I return "false", they are called but then, the touch processing that the class ImageZoomView did **simply don't happen**! (I guess because I returned "false" in the end, so Android simply ignores any UI updates that the touch events of the class com.sonyericsson.zoom.ImageZoomView previous made).

In short, I want to be able to process the same touch event in both my com.sonyericsson.zoom.ImageZoomView AND in my RelativeLayout.

Is there any way to do that?

I am using Android 2.2+.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the method *onInterceptTouchEvent*, like below :

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        return onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

I had to implement the method *onTouchEvent* to return "false":

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

      gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);      
   return false;
}
```

That way I was able to intercept the events BEFORE they get send to the children. So, I made de processing I wanted before that.

Comment: Can you provide full code?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you moving the logic in **OnTouchListener** of ImageZoomView to **dispatchTouchEvent** method.

In the problems I run into before, I found that dispatchTouchEvent/dispatchKeyEvent usually works while onTouchListener/onKeyListener not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from the `ImageZoomView` class.

This inherited class has a reference to your RelativeLayout.

Override the touch handling method and put the following pseudo code in:

```
bool result = super.onTouch();
referencedRelativeLayout.onTouch();
return result;
```

That way both widgets get the event.

Answer (score 0):

Lest say that your `ImageZoomView` class extends `View`, on your main activity you could do something like:

```
ImageZoomView mView;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);       

    mView = (ImageZoomView) findViewById(R.id.zoomview);         
    mView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        //Do whatever
        return false;
    });        

}
```

Just treat `ImageZoomView` like if it was a button(which extends from View).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying 0gravity. But that is the thing, if I return false there, the event will be passed to the next view, ok (that is what I want). However, for some reason, all the processing that was made just before that "return false;" (inside the onTouch method) is IGNORED by Android! That is, only the processing of the next view (in my case, RelativeLayout) will be processed. I don't want the processing of the ImageZoomView to be ignored!!

Comment: The only way I can make it not to be ignored is by returning true instead of false. However, in that case, the event will not be passed to the next view (RelativeLayout)...